# There are no run,debug icons on right-up side in the pycharm

Tags: pycharm

other people have run,debug,etc icons on the right-up side but i couldn't find the settings for them.
how can I setup to display run,debug icon on the right-up side of the pycharm??

Comment: Please add more information to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable "ToolBar" as mentioned below,

[image]

Then, you can customize the same by right-clicking
[image] on the toolbar